# real analysis - Meaning of sequence in normed space

Tags: real-analysis

1) I have a question regarding the definition of "sequence" in the following sentence:

> In a normed space, every convergence sequence is Cauchy".

I wonder if anyone could provide an example of what this "sequence" may look like?

2) For example, I have the following quote from [here](http://web.mit.edu/14.102/www/notes/lecturenotes1021.pdf):

> In $\Bbb{R}^{k}$, every Cauchy sequence converges.

How many "elements" are contained in this sequence? Let's say $k = 2$ and we have a plane ($\Bbb{R}^{2}$), does this sequence contain all the points in this plane?

Also, what is the meaning of "every" in every Cauchy sequence?  Let's say $k = 2$ and we have a plane ($\Bbb{R}^{2}$), does the combination of every Cauchy sequence contain all the points in this plane?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: A sequence in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will be a sequence $\{(x_n, y_n)\}$ of two-tuples such that $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. An example could be the sequence $\{(1 + \frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})\}$ which would converge to $(1, 0)$.

Comment: The elements of the sequence are countable many,  on the other hand the elements of the plane are uncountable.

Comment: Thank you for you help. But I wonder how to find "every" Cauchy sequence. For example, what would be an intuitive understanding of every cauchy sequence in $R^{2}$ ?

Comment: In finite dimensions, as you say, every Cauchy sequence converges. So, if you want to picture a Cauchy sequence in $2$ or $3$ dimensions, picture a convergent sequence; they're same thing. If you want to picture a Cauchy sequence that doesn't converge, you'll either need to picture infinite dimensions, or you'll have to picture a metric space of some kind (which isn't hard to do, but I think is outside the scope of this question).

Comment: @Yalun The property that every Cauchy sequence converges is called "completeness". A normed space that is complete is called a Banach Space. Check wikipedia for some more info.

Comment: Thank you all. I understand that convergence part, but I'm having a hard time understanding why we need to highlight "every". I wonder if you may briefly explain it?

Comment: @Yalun You will drive yourself crazy trying to imagine or visualize every single Cauchy sequence. Instead try to think of "Every" as: Given any Cauchy sequence in our (complete) space, we know that it will converge. This is a desirable property for a normed vector space to have.